# Wrapping Lua API in Java

Tags: java, api, scala, lua, wrapper

I'm trying to write a large scale project in Java/Scala(a JVM language) that extends a preexisting program, but the problem is that the API is written in Lua.

I have found a list of websites that claim to be able to access Java from Lua and Lua from Java:

1. http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/
2. http://code.google.com/p/jnlua/
3. https://www.github.com/dafrito/jna-lua

The program in which my project is extending, works by loading a certain script within a file.  Instead, I want to run everything from a JVM project.

In other works:  I need to be able to call functions within a Lua file that is loaded via a reflection-like system from a java project.

Has anyone done something like this before? Is it possible? Would you recommend a certain library for Java <-> Lua connection? Would you recommend an alternative?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [LuaJ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/) or [Kahlua](https://github.com/krka/kahlua2). I have used both, and they work. LuaJava works as well as jnlua. I know projects using both though I don't myself.

So you have 4 to pick from. There isn't a "best" one, each one has some pluses and minuses. It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Do you think the idea its self is possible?

Comment: I use it in my Lua IDE (based on IntelliJ), the goal was to allow Lua developers to extend the IDE using Lua.

For example: https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Setting_Up_Custom_Documentation